# Соединение с ораклом из веб-интерфейса

Tags: oracle, php

Добрый день! У меня вопрос следующий как правильно подключиться к базе оракла?
В мануале читал что для этого используется oci_connect. Так вот делаю примерно такую строку:

```
$conn = oci_connect('username', 'password', 'localhost/conn');
```

А насчет третьего параметра не знаю даже как сделать. Читал, что надо искать параметр Connect Name в файле tnsnames.ora, но там ничего подобного не нашел. Подскажите, те кто уже прошел этот путь). И еще кому не трудно как через PDO подключение это будет выглядеть тоже самое. Буду благодарен за ответ! Версия оракла 11g, php 5.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добрый день!

Лучше используй **PDO** для этого (собственно как ты и написал):

1. проверь есть ли в папке ext (где установлен PHP у тебя) библиотека php_pdo_oci.dll
2. затем добавь или раскомменть строчку с этой библиотекой в php.ini
3. подключение через `PDO $db = new PDO('oci:dbname='.$database, charset=CL8MSWIN1251', 'username', 'password');`
4. Читай мануалы по PDO (выборки, вставка, удаление и тд)

Как пример (в продолжение подключения):

```
   $data = $db->prepare('SELECT * from DB'); // готовим запрос
    $data->execute(); // запуск

// перебор результата
    while($row = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

        echo $row->elementDB."\n";

    }
```

Comment: Скачал для проверки такой файл закинул в папку ext, но никакого результата это не дало. Такое ощущение что не состыковка с oci.dll от oracle идет просто...потому все так происходит. Подскажите как решить эту проблему! Реальный совет дайте, друзья!

Comment: А не пробовали

    download php 5.2 oracle php_pdo_oci dll

в гугле?

Comment: @avp, подобные запросы пробовал вводить. Скачивал версию 5.1 и 5.4. php_pdo_oci.dll  с ними не работало все равно. Конкретно для 5.2 не нашел версию библиотеки.

Comment: Ну что кто-нибудь знает как победить эту ошибку мне с неизвестной функцией oci_connect()? У кого какие идеи и соображения по этому поводу есть? У оракла все в порядке, клиент стоит тоже. Не знаю даже что делать-то...

Comment: Значит просто не видит библиотеку, раз пишет "Call to undefined function oci_connect() in I:\home\localhost\www\1\index.php on line 2".
наберите phpinfo(); и запустите, посмотрите есть ли там библиотека php_pdo_oci.dll и где лежит файл php.ini в каталоге где php установлен, или в windows, или еще где. Может вы не там прописали подключаемую библиотеку.
Хотя, вы же сами в начале говорили, что будете использовать PDO и зачем вам oci_connect? В dll - php_pdo_oci.dll не копался, но может там ее действительно нет, даже если все норм подключено. Попробуйте поискать, разобраться самостоятельно.